# Confusion regarding SI units of K (stiffnes)

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, unit

I know that stiffness, **K** is equal to product of moment of inertia and square of  natural frequency

**K = Jωn<sup>2</sup>**

Where K = stifness, J = moment of inertia and ωn = natural frequency

SI unit of J is kg m<sup>2</sup>, while SI unit of ωn,natural frequecny is **rad/s** but as shown in attached snap, SI unit of K is **(Nm)/rad**. I have tried to solve and simplify the product of units of J and ωn<sup>2</sup>, but I am unable to understand how we get unit of K as **(Nm)/rad** because I get units as **(Nm)rad<sup>2</sup>**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: In a sense, it doesn't matter.  An angle in radians is a quotient of two lengths (arc length and radius of a circular sector that subtends that angle), so a radian is interchangeable with unity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the stiffness $K$ should be just a relation between an angle of rotation $\varphi$ [rad] and moment $M$ [Nm], so the its unit is [Nm/rad]:

$$K = \frac{M}{\varphi}$$

(there has to be an angular spring)

On the other hand, changing angular velocity $\omega$ [rad/s] of an object requires application of moment $M$ [Nm] for some time [s] and the resistance to this change is proportional to the moment of inertia $J$:

$$J = \frac{M}{\frac{d\omega}{ds}}; kg\cdot m^2 = \frac{N\cdot m}{\frac{rad}{s^2}}$$

(there has to be a rotating mass)

Since $N = kg\cdot m\cdot s^{-2}$, it should be correct.

Comment: Is K the same thing as rotational kinetic energy? https://byjus.com/physics/rotational-kinetic-energy/

Comment: No, its more like a spring stiffness. When you have shaft with spiral spring, then the moment $M$ required to hold the shaft at rotation $\varphi$ would be given by $M = K\cdot \varphi$.